# Access column name from a contextMenuEvent in PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview

Working with a `QTableView`, I added a  `contextMenuEvent` to the headers. I need to get access to the column header I clicked on to do things with the column name.

Some code :

```
class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.horizontalHeader().setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.horizontalHeader().customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.selectMenu)


    def selectMenu(self, event):
        """ A right click on a column name allows the info to be displayed in the graphView """
        menu = QMenu(self)
        selectAction = QAction("Display on graph", self)
        menu.addAction(selectAction)
        menu.popup(QCursor.pos())
        print(type(self.horizontalHeader())) # returns QHeaderView
```

Unfortunatly there is no function in the `QHeaderView` class to retrieve the header data.

I also tried to access the column using the `QTableView.columnAt()` function :

```
print(self.columnAt(QCursor.pos().x())) # returns -1
```

As you can see it doesn't work since the QCursor is not on a "valid index" according to the `QTableView` documentation.

**EDIT**

Works using `event.x()` instead of `QCursor.pos().x()`

```
print(self.columnAt(event.x())) # returns the column index or -1 if not a valid column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QCursor.pos()` returns global coordinates (and displays the current mouse location, not the location at which the event originated). Use `QContextMenuEvent.pos()` instead, which is in local widget coordinates.

If you really, really want to use `QCursor.pos()` to get the current mouse position, use the table's `mapFromGlobal()` method (inherited from `QWidget`) to translate to local coordinates.

```
def selectMenu(self, event):
    """ A right click on a column name allows the info to be displayed in the graphView """
    menu = QMenu(self)
    selectAction = QAction("Display on graph", self)
    menu.addAction(selectAction)
    menu.popup(event.pos())
    print(type(self.horizontalHeader())) # returns QHeaderView
    print(self.columnAt(event.x()))
```

Comment: The last line you corrected thows an error. You should correct it with `columnAt(event.x())` which works fine for me. Thanks =)